# Can I use youtube-dl to provide the direct links and use other means to download them?

Tags: youtube-dl

Specifically, I would like to use DownloadThemAll. Can I use youtube-dl to just give me the direct link I need?

Comment: Use -f best to get video and audio merged.
https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/8818

Answer (score 45):

Sure, you can.

Use the `--get-url` option to extract the direct link to media. For example:

```
youtube-dl --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the noob questions, I did manage to figure it out.  I am working on something to replace some of the functionality of BYTubeD since it was abandond long ago and I fear one day it will stop working.  So far I have made [this.](https://github.com/GraySloth/YouTube-dl2HTML)

Comment: this method only get video and audio apart, can't get video and audio mixed together.